# How to update dataset.datatable bound to datagridview via another thread

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, datagridview

Hi I have a dataset that contains a few tables.
One of these tables is bound to a bindingsource which is then to a datagridview.

The dataset table is updated via a single background thread as it fetches the data via http

This obviously causes the datagridview to throw a cross threading error as its being updated from a different thread.

My question is how to I get around this without doing a complete rewrite? I realise I could have the UI thread update the dataset from some sort of buffer that the background thread creates but thats starting again and I would like to check there is not a simpler way that Ive missed.  Most of the examples I see on here seem like I need to start again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are not using async/await.

You can use `Invoke()` to run something on the UI thread.

```
Task.Run(new Action(() =>
{
    // << do http call >>

    this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
    {
        //manipulate grid here.....
    }));
}));
```

Ideally you would be using async/await. It is kind of a waste to run IO bound code with Task.Run.

Comment: You don't need to create `new Action`, you just can do this: `Task.Run(() => ...);`

Comment: @VMAtm good point. I think they end up identical when compiled but concise is better.

Comment: You are right Im not using async/await.  I hadnt tried this method as I presumed it would give me the same error it being a different thread.
Also it seems using Invoke to pass the dataset manipulation stuff back the the UI thread causes it to become lock up and become more unresponsive I guess due to the processing time for the data.  Im going to have to have a rethink and start again on this by the looks.

Comment: The task is run on another thread but `Invoke` runs its delegate on the thread that owns the window handle.

Comment: This is wrong, or incomplete, because Invoke is only meant to update GUI in the same GUI thread, not to delay the GUI thread by running SqlAdapter.Update(datatable) as this answer implies,

Comment: @RaidenCore there is no sql adapter here, data comes from an http call, which I show, as a comment, outside of the invoke.

Comment: I decided to remove my downvote, but can I do that ?

Comment: @RaidenCore as far as I know you can't remove a downvote. It seems like you can only upvote. Something I never understood about SO. No worries though.